# Ubuntu Display repeats itself

Tags: display, resolution, flicker

I blew away Windows XP using the Ubuntu disk today on my Dell Inspiron 1100.  After Linux installed and I rebooted, the display of Ubuntu seems to repeat itself.  So I have two login screens, and each doesn't extend to the far right side of the monitor.

I went to the Dell site to download the drivers, but I didn't see an option for a Linux operating system.

What could cause this?  How can I fix it?

===============
Problem 2: the screen also keeps flickering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a fresh install and you have logged in for the first time, you may need to install and activate proprietary drivers. From the dash, search `jockey` or "Additional Drivers" to check for any display drivers you might need to install.

Once your drivers are up-to-date, you can change your display settings by selecting `Displays` from the cog icon system menu in the top right of the screen (or use the dash to search for "Displays")

Comment: what's the "dash"?  I also can't find a search box anywhere.

Comment: to get to the dash, click on the ubuntu logo up near the top left corner of the launcher, or press the super-key (windows key) -- sorry, I'm assuming you are using the latest stable release (ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: Looks like it needs to be plugged into the internet to download the drivers.  Something I didn't do when I installed Ubuntu.  I'm thinking I should just do a clean install with it plugged in, to have it automatically install other things it missed.  What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: well you could do that, but why not just plug it in now and get all the updates?

Comment: just boot into a unity2D session when you login which will use a less graphics-intensive desktop. install all the updates etc,  reboot, and log back in with the regular (3D) unity

Comment: Okay.  I just wasn't sure if there was more that I missed, other than just 'Additional Drivers'.  So is unity2D sort of like safe mode for Linux?

Comment: unity2D just uses minimal graphics and is designed for older systems that don't have the hardware specs to run 3D graphics

Comment: even though I couldn't get it working on that laptop, I'm marking this as correct.  My network card is bad on my laptop.  :-)  I got it working on another computer last night.